# iPhone and MacBook Pro with a single wireless headset

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, bluetooth, headphones

Is it possible to have a single wireless headset that works simultaneously with both an iPhone and a MacBook Pro?

Imagine this scenario: I am watching video on my screen, listening via my wireless headset. My phone rings. To answer it now, I have to remove my headset and put on the second headset paired with my phone.

In scenario two I am having a Skype call on my computer when my phone rings.

In the first scenario I need only need to receive at my headset from one device and send and receive from the second. In the second scenario I need to send and receive with both devices.

Is this possible with a single headset?

Answer (score 1):

I know there are some Bluetooth headphones [(such as these ones that I can talk about from personal experience)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00M1B55JM) that come with an optional audio cable, enabling them to be used as a standard pair of wired headphones in case the pairing malfunctions or something. It has the really awesome side effect of enabling the headphones to play two streams of audio at once: Pair them with one device wirelessly and plug them into another.

I know, it's not a perfect solution, but it's the best one I've seen so far.

Comment: I like where you are going with this. Alas, the particular ones you have experience with are headphones rather than a headset that includes a microphone which is what I require.

Comment: These ones have a microphone. I've never used it so I can't vouch for its quality, but I know it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have the Jabra REVO Wireless headphones and they are able to connect to 2 devices at the same time allowing for what you are looking to do.

http://www.jabra.com/Products/Bluetooth/JABRA_REVO_Wireless/Jabra_REVO_WIRELESS

They don't really say it anywhere on their support documentation but this review on Amazon explains it pretty well (look for Multipoint section):

http://www.amazon.com/review/R2PTODOLO53PFW/ref=cm_cr_pr_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00BFO14W8

I've had them for a few months and they are great!